# KML to Shapefile losing Fields in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, kmz

I am trying to convert KML File to shapefile, but all the fields are being deleted except the name.

How can I convert a KML/KMZ file to shapefile without losing the fields?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @elieelalam! Did you try using the **KML to Layer** tool from the [KML Toolset](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/an-overview-of-the-kml-toolset.htm)?

Comment: yes but my fields are being deleted

Comment: Are your fields actual "ExtendedData" fields in the KML code, or are they just text in the HTML balloon descriptions? If they are separated out as name/value pairs in the KML's ExtendedData sections, then you should be able to convert to shapefile attributes.  But if they are simply HTML blobs in the KML's description tags, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert from kmz to gdb and after export to shapefile.
But field name's (shp file) can not contain more than 10 characters.

If this don't help, try use

1. [Datainteroperability](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability)
2. [GIS converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/)